# getSkuDetails() returns empty result for subscriptions in IAB V3

Tags: android

I am using in App Billing Version 3.

when i query for SKU details of Managed Product , I am getting results.

But when i query for SKU details of Subscription , it returns empty list

```
skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, 
                        getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
```

can anyone help in this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when i change the product type as "subs" it works.

```
skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "subs", querySkus)
```

Comment: but subs is for subscriptions!

Comment: Thanks! You've saved my day :) As usual stupid google's docs!